# Column Count vs Value Count on insert statement - PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working on building an employee database but seem to have run into an interesting issue.
When I run my query to add a new user/employee, I get the error:

> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

From what I have researched, this seems to be an error with inserting more/less values than what is declared in the first part of an insert statement example:

> INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES (val1, val2, val3)

The thing is though, I have looked over my query and the columns and values match perfectly (count wise). I have even looked for things in my query such as missing quotes, commas, etc.

Here is my code (query):

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO userdata (
                Username,
                Email,
                Phone,
                Password,
                FirstName,
                LastName,
                Address,
                City,
                State,
                Zip,
                JobTitle,
                UserGroup,
                JobStatus,
                Points,
                Status,
                BirthDate,
                HireDate,
                HourlyRate,
                DateAdded,
                SSN
            ) VALUES (
                '$Username',
                '$Email',
                '$Phone',
                '$Password',
                '$FirstName',
                '$LastName',
                '$Address',
                '$City',
                '$State',
                '$Zip',
                '$JobTitle',
                '$Group',
                '$JobStatus',
                0,
                '$Status',
                '$BirthDate',
                '$HireDate',
                '$HourlyRate'
                '$TodaysDate',
                '$SSN'
            )") or die(mysqli_error($db));
```

Some things to note:

- This not all of the columns in the table have data inserted here (I think its possible to do this and things such as auto incrementing ID's will fill themselves in and others will be left blank)
- From the variable dumps I have done, all of these variables are valid.

I am really confused about this and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Column `UserGroup` appears twice; `JobTitle`, `UserGroup` and `JobStatus` appear to be in the wrong order

Comment: I take it that `SSN` is "Social Security Number" and hope it's not a mandatory field ;-)

Comment: SSN is indeed the social, but its only the last few digits for accounting purposes. I have updated the OP to the new query and I still get the same error :(

Comment: Missing comma after `'$HourlyRate'` value

Comment: I thought I checked everything, That was it, thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

Check the following  portion again:

```
    INSERT INTO userdata(...,
                    JobStatus,
                    UserGroup,
                    Points,
                    UserGroup,
                    Status,
                    .....
            ,)VALUES(...,
                   $JobStatus',
                   0,
                  '$Group',
                   '$Status',
                   ......
                   )
```

In values(, ?, ?, ?), after jobstatus, there should be UserGroup and then Points. And UserGroup appeared twice.

Comment: oops, I had accidentally duplicated that column when I was looking for a fix/moving things around, I have updated the query in the original post. edit: still get the same error :(

Comment: Try inserting with the autoincreament_feild/primarykey_feild with value 'NULL' for the query and let us know.